# CTRL-F (FIND) together with LAZYLOAD feature of FULLPAGE.JS

Tags: image, scroll, find, fullpage.js, lazy-loading

A question about the Fullpage plugin: http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/

Fullpage.js creates a fullpage scrolling website design if you use this Jquery plugin on your website.
If you prefer you can add image tags to this website using attribute "data-src" instead of "src" which will lazy load images (they only show up when you scroll to them). This works perfectly, but not when you do a search on the page (CTRL-F). In that case it jumps to the right section and the right word on the page, and if that is a page with images, those images will not show up.
There undoubtedly would be a solution for that, but does anybody knows a solution?

Comment: If you use fullpage for scrolling and lazysizes for lazyloading, it should work, (https://github.com/aFarkas/lazysizes). But you will need to configure lazysizes to take different attributes. For example `data-original` instead of `data-src` otherwise there is the possibility, that fullpage interferes with lazysizes. (It would be better to have an option to stop fullpage lazyloading). for option changing: https://github.com/aFarkas/lazysizes#js-api---options

Comment: I will test this. Are you sure it works with CTRL-F? Because that is an issue in Fullpage.js.

Comment: Thank you, Alexander Farkas, it works. If you want you can add your comment as an answer and I will mark him as the right answer for me. You're right it's better to let Fullpage stop lazyloading, because I also saw there were only some images not lazyloading, but other images load lazy perfectly and it works with CTRL-F, great solution!

Comment: You can not use ANY lazy loading libraries unless you use `scrollBar:true` or `autoScrolling:false` in fullpage.js. They won't work otherwise.

Comment: But the lazy loading library of Mr. Farkas is doing a good job.

Comment: @Alvaro But lazysizes is not ANY other lazyloader. https://github.com/aFarkas/lazysizes/#what-makes-lazysizes-so-awesome

Answer (score 0):

> There undoubtedly would be a solution for that,

Not really.

There's [an open issue in fullpage.js issues forum](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/issues/1292) and no solution has been found for it yet.

The only solution is using the fullpage.js options `scrollBar:true` or `autoScrolling:false`. which will create a normal scroll bar on the site.

Comment: certainly helpful, but it's no solution for me. I chose Fullpage.js because it's pretty unique to show a fixed top menu on all devices, also older iOS devices, even when you scroll content. The option scrollBar:true destroys that excellent feature of Fullpage.js. Because it's not only a Fullpage problem, maybe a non-Fullpage user who knows everything about detecting which images are in the viewport / are viewed, and trigger Lazyload that way, has the solution for this case!

Comment: Problem is that Lazyload doesn't work because with Fullpage there's no scroll position recognized by the browser on CRTL-F. Do I describe that right?

Comment: Solution found in the comments below my original question. Lazysizes works with Fullpage and CTRL-F (find). Question for you: How to replace Fullpage Lazyload with Lazysizes?